# CGI - card reader

Tags: cgi, lazarus

I made software to access and read smart card from card reader.
When software is organized as a desktop application it works perfect, but I need it to work as CGI.
I am using lazarus, and in execution process I am receiving error code:-2146435043
as the card smart resource manager is not running.
Any suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Bojan

Comment: Did you start the "Smart Card"-service in services.msc?

Comment: Yes the service is started. And desktop application with the same code works perfect.

Comment: You could still check if it's running as "LocalService". If so you could check if the event-logs give you some more information. Is the webservice you're using your cgi with also running as LocalService? NETWORK SERVICE or **non-interactive** users (i.e. apache) don't have access to it. I don't have any experience with this but it's a starting point.